# Saving a file causes multiple "File Event [change]" when only one file has been changed

Tags: laravel, npm, homestead, browser-sync, laravel-mix

When using "npm run watch", I save the file and i get multiple file changed events when i have only saved one file.

I have read through documents for browser sync and i cant seem to find anything about only monitoring one file.

```
  /css/admin.css  38.3 KiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
    /css/app.css   128 KiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
\css\general.css   135 KiB           [emitted]
 + 1 hidden asset
[Browsersync] File event [change] : public\css\app.css
[Browsersync] File event [change] : public\css\admin.css
[Browsersync] File event [change] : public\css\admin.css
[Browsersync] File event [change] : public\css\app.css
[Browsersync] File event [change] : public\css\general.css
```

Comment: For providing right answer include your `webpack.mix` file config.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.

What webpack is doing makes sense. Those files where changing because they were being compiled every time i saved.

What i did to resolve the issue was to tell Webpack to watch my scss, js & blade files instead.